# Curlies used in dynamic fields are not resolved

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I have a `nodeAliasPath` input field which alters other fields:

```js
inputFields: [
{
  key: 'nodeAliasPath',
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  label: 'Node alias path',
  helpText: 'The path of the page to update. For example, "/Blogs/Food"',
  altersDynamicFields: true
},
...
```

My other (dynamic) field calls `getPageData` with the `nodeAliasPath` to make a `z.request`

```js
inputFields: [
async function (z, bundle) {
  const pageData = await getPageData(z, bundle, bundle.inputData.nodeAliasPath, bundle.inputData.culture);
  if(!pageData) throw new z.errors.HaltedError(`Page not found. Please check the Node Alias Path and Culture.` );
  else return await getPageColumnsField(z, bundle, pageData["NodeClassID"], pageData);
},
...
```

The `updatePage` function uses `{{bundle.inputData.nodeAliasPath}}` to get the provided input:

```js
const options = {
        url: `{{bundle.authData.website}}/rest/content/currentsite`
            + `/${data.DocumentCulture}/document{{bundle.inputData.nodeAliasPath}}`,
```

But, when the request runs I can see in the *Monitoring* tab of Zapier Platform that the request performed is actually **/document{{114648603__NodeAliasPath}}**. This only happens if I try to pull a value from a previous step- if I type in some value, the request looks perfect and runs fine.

How can I resolve the curlies in the URL to get the actual value of the field from another step? The dynamic fields in the current step rely on the results of this request.

Answer (score 0):

We discussed this in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/issues/336), but the gist is that **in the Zap editor, custom fields can't depend on mapped fields**.